# Dynamically loading an assembly

Tags: c#, excel

I need to dynamically load an assembly. Currently I am working with "Microsoft.Office.Microsoft.Office.Interop.dll". I need to open an excel file and get the sheets and data out of it. Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly
          .Load("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c");

if (SampleAssembly != null)
{
    Type type = SampleAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass");
    Object AppClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

   //How will I get ApplicationClass object and Workbooks objects here?
}
```

Comment: Seem you use.NET 3.5 instead of .net 4?

Comment: Also, check this workaround: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10888/SafeCOMWrapper-Managed-Disposable-Strongly-Typed-s

Answer (score 3):

Take advantage of `dynamic`:

```
 Type type = SampleAssembly.GetTypes().Single(t => t.Name == "ApplicationClass");
 dynamic appClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

 var workbook = appClass.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.csv");
 var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting the below error : Error 1 Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported. and 2. One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and System.Core.dll?

Comment: @sharmila: weird, which version of .NET are you using? and Exception thrown in which line?

Comment: I am working with asp.net application and the error is bec of missing microsoft.csharp dll. I cant find this dll in .net assemblies(add references)

Comment: @sharmila: which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @sharmila: no update so far, seem complicated with .NET 3.5 on problem using reflection calling Open method, just wait others answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17212/discussion-between-cuong-le-and-sharmila)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't/do not want to use dynamics, I would define a project with an interface (or a set of interfaces) exposing the excel methods/objects you need to use and that you can reference in your code without any ref to the actual excel dll. Then implement it in a different project which references excel and which will be loaded dynamically.

Something like this:

```
public interface IExcelApp
{
    IExcelWorkbook OpenWbk(string aPath);
    // other stuff
}

public interface IExcelWorkbook
{
    //the stuff you need
}
```

The implementation (in a project I called for instance ExcelBridge):

```
public class ExcelApp : IExcelApp
{
    private ApplicationClass _app;

    public ExcelApp()
    {
    }

    public IExcelWorkbook OpenWbk(string aPath)
    {
        return new ExcelWorkbook(_app.Workbooks.Open(aPath));
    }
}

public class ExcelWorkbook : IExcelWorkbook
{
    private Workbook _wbk;

    public ExcelWorkbook(Workbook aWbk)
    {
        _wbk = aWbk;
    }
}
```

Then your code could be like this:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.Load("ExcelBridge", Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c");

if (SampleAssembly != null)
{
    Assembly YourExcelAssembly = Assembly.Load("ExcelBridge.dll");
    Type type = YourExcelAssembly .GetType("ExcelApp");
    IExcel AppClass = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IExcelApp;

   //now you can write:
   IExcelWorkBook aWbk = AppClass.Open("your xls path");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it in C#

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Type type = SampleAssembly.GetType("Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass");
var application = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;
```

Comment: I need to load the assembly dynamically and call methods.

Comment: Yes, I have loaded the assembly at runtime. Now i need to access the attributes of the assembly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 3.5 you can't use the `dynamic` keyword. Your only option is to use a series of proxy classes (written manually or generated automatically) as described by @Francesco. But the manual approach is really cumbersome if you need to access a lot of Excel classes/functions/properties. You have to write a function/property proxy for each and every members you need.

The key to manage this is, instead of writing a lot of proxy functions, you put all the codes dealing with Excel in a separate software layer (something like Data Access Layer, DAL) placed in a different library project. This layer just provides some high-level interfaces (with only a few member functions) to the application such that the application doesn't even know about the usage of MS Excel automation.

Note that this encapsulation of Excel access codes is a good practice even if you didn't want to dynamically load the assembly. For example you may rather easily replace Office Automation, if you found it frustrating, with another technology like ADO.NET with `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider for [reading from / writing to Excel files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934/en-us), which you also find frustrating within x64 platforms!

For example, if you want to grab sheet and data from an Excel file, you can provide the following interface inside a project named, say, `Utils.OfficeAutomation` (with no reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`):

```
interface IExcelLayer {
    ...
    bool ImportFrom(string fileName, string sheetName, out object[,] cells, bool skipHeaderRow = true);

    // a few other members...
    ...
}
```

Then implement it in a separate project named, say `Utils.OfficeAutomation.Impl`, which references both `Utils.OfficeAutomation` and the real `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`:

```
class ExcelMagician : IExcelLayer {
    ...
    bool ImportFrom(string fileName, string sheetName, out object[,] cells, bool skipHeaderRow = true)
    {
         Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application()
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The main application only has a reference to `Utils.OfficeAutomation`. In return, `Utils.OfficeAutomation` is somehow responsible for dynamically finding and loading `Utils.OfficeAutomation.Impl`, or generate an error if something went wrong:

```
IExcelLayer m_instance = null;

...

try
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("Utils.OfficeAutomation.Impl");
    Type excelType = assembly.GetType("Utils.OfficeAutomation.Impl.ExcelMagician");
    m_instance = (IExcelLayer) Activator.CreateInstance(excelType);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception("Couldn't load Excel assembly.")
}
```

If an appropriate version of Microsoft Excel is not installed, either loading the assembly `Utils.OfficeAutomation.Impl` fails, or calling members like `ImportFrom` generates an exception.

You finally need to write wrapper classes inside `Utils.OfficeAutomation` as Excel Access Layer or a gateway to Excel functionality.